# How to add a field using xml from existing fieldset created using php

Tags: uicomponent, adminform, wysiwyg, fieldsets

I have a module where I'm overriding some of it's feauture to match what I need. So everything is working but I need to add an editor wysiwyg field into the existing form using an xml (uicomponent) but the module built the forms using php (setField & renderer).

Is there a way I can do this? becaue I really have to be able to create an additional field using xml and not php.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/ui_component**

***product_form.xml***

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="[Fieldet_Name]">
          <field name="new_column">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">New Column</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">new_column</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">new_column</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/layout**

***catalog_product_form.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="product_form"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Note: Please make a sure which ui_component name which you want to add  Layout name and file name must be same**

***I Hope This Helps You***

Comment: I'll try this suggestion of yours and will let you know if this works for me. Thanks

Comment: @bryanxkier let me inform it's works for you ?

Comment: how can I set that layout xml and ui component on my custom module? because I have to use this on my blog/news module @Msquare